# Creating a new database for second project on Prostgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, heroku

I am starting a new project and want to use Postgres as my database. How can I implement a new database for this project with Postgres without causing problems with the other database I am using for another project?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Not sure if it matters but these two projects have two different heroku accounts.

Comment: Hi! I think what matters is that both of your projects have their own separate git repos. Everything else is handled by **Heroku** itself. If you want to use Postgres just add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile into the  `group :production do` block.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the question with the `heroku` tag. Heroku will take care of this for you.

Locally, you should first create a new user:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s your_user_name
```

For local development you can make this a super-user. Heroku will use sensible defaults in production.

Done that, configure your rails app and then create your db:

```
bin/rake db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: I am already using Postgres for another project though. I would create a separate username like you are saying then for this project?

Comment: Postgres, like most ORDBMS, will support multiple databases. Each DB has a name, and they are isolated from each other. As long as your apps use different names for their DBs (configured in `config/database.yml`), you're good to go. This, of course, is something you need to worry about in your local dev environment (your computer). Heroku will take care of this for you when you push/deploy.